# c# implementation of primus websocket

Tags: c#, websocket, primus

There is a web server (nodeJs) that I want to connect to using c#. The server accepts connections comming from primus websocket (javascript) and I am looking for an implmentation of that for c# but it seems that it doesn't exist.

Is anyone here knows some alternative way to connect to the server?

Thank you.